# AngularJS how to recover answers from an html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good morning,
I have started AngularJS like 2 days ago and I'm trying to do an exercice which is a form with three questions (for now) each question have 3 answers and each answer have a score which determines after a calculation to which category the user answering belongs.

What I have done till now:

```js
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('qcmController', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = [{
      name: 'humain',
      description: 'categorie humain',
      score: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Dev',
      description: 'categorie Developpeur',
      score: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Nos Nos',
      description: 'categorie Mis-dev,Mis-humain',
      score: 0
    }
  ];


  $scope.qst = [{
      label: 'Aimez-vous Ruby ?',
      rep: [{
          label: 'j"adore',
          categorie: 'dev',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: 'oui',
          categorie: 'Nos Nos',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: 'C"est quoi Ruby ?',
          categorie: 'humain',
          point: '10'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      label: 'c"est quoi Java ?',
      rep: [{
          label: 'Langage de programation',
          categorie: 'dev',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: 'Langage',
          categorie: 'Nos Nos',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: '9ahwa :) ?',
          categorie: 'humain',
          point: '10'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Vous aimez la programation?',
      rep: [{
          label: 'j"adore',
          categorie: 'dev',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: 'oui',
          categorie: 'Nos Nos',
          point: '10'
        },
        {
          label: 'c"est quoi la programation ?',
          categorie: 'humain',
          point: '10'
        }
      ]
    },
  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="qcmController">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cat in categories">
        <b ng-bind="cat.name"></b>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="question in qst">
          <b ng-bind="question.label"></b>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="rep in question.rep">
              <input type="checkbox"> <span ng-bind="rep.label"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is I have no idea how can I recover the answer so I can calculate that score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ng-model` on the checkbox you can store a `selected` boolean. Check out the console log object of the item you select when submitting:

```
<form ng-submit="calc()">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="question in qst">
        <b ng-bind="question.label"></b>
        <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="rep in question.rep">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rep.selected"> <span ng-bind="rep.label"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
```

**app.js**

```
app=angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('qcmController', function($scope){
    $scope.categories = 
    [
        {name: 'humain', description:'categorie humain', score: 0},
        {name: 'Dev', description:'categorie Developpeur', score: 0},
        {name: 'Nos Nos', description:'categorie Mis-dev,Mis-humain', score: 0}
    ];


    $scope.qst = 
    [
        {label:'Aimez-vous Ruby ?', rep :[{label:'j"adore', categorie:'dev', point:'10'},
                                        {label:'oui', categorie:'Nos Nos', point:'10'},
                                        {label:'C"est quoi Ruby ?', categorie:'humain', point:'10'}  ]},

        {label:'c"est quoi Java ?', rep :[{label:'Langage de programation', categorie:'dev', point:'10'},
                                        {label:'Langage', categorie:'Nos Nos', point:'10'},
                                        {label:'9ahwa :) ?', categorie:'humain', point:'10'}  ]},
        {label:'Vous aimez la programation?', rep :[{label:'j"adore', categorie:'dev', point:'10'},
                                                    {label:'oui', categorie:'Nos Nos', point:'10'},
                                                    {label:'c"est quoi la programation ?', categorie:'humain', point:'10'}  ]},
    ];

    $scope.calc = function () {
        console.log($scope.qst);
    };
})
```